# Using the full number instead of 525.31e+10

Tags: python, python-3.x, primes, largenumber

I've written a program that can find prime numbers.

```
from time import sleep
soNotPrimes = []
n = input("Start finding primes at: ")
n = int(n)
k = 2
found_factors = 0
nSQRT = n**0.5
while True:
    kinn = n/k
    if found_factors == 1:
        print("Okay, look man, I totally found a non-prime number. It's", n)
        n += 1
        k = 2
        found_factors = 0
        nSQRT = n**0.5
        continue

    if (k > nSQRT) and found_factors == 0:
        print("Oh yeah man, I found a prime!", n)
        n += 1
        k = 2
        found_factors = 0
        nSQRT = n**0.5
        continue


    if kinn.is_integer():
        found_factors += 1

    k += 1
```

However, this does not work, because if the numbers get high enough, Python starts interpreterting them as, for example, 525.31e+10. This will always be equal to something like 5253100000000, which is not prime, as it is an even number. Is there a way to make Python interpret these numbers literally?

Comment: No, if these numbers are integers, Python will have their proper integer representation in memory; you're probably just looking at the output, the representation given by print.

Comment: Alternatively, you're turning your integers into floats. For example, you have a division like `n/k`. Use integer division instead `n//k` (assuming that that is what you want). Use different algorithms to test for divisibility than testing a float with `.is_integer()`. For example, use the modulo `%` operator instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't reproduce your issue but generally speaking, we want to avoid floating point from creeping into our results and our comparisons.  There are two places this happens in your code:

```
kinn = n/k
```

which we can replace with the modulus `%` to get an integer remainder instead of float, and:

```
nSQRT = n**0.5
```

which we can replace with comparing `k` squared against `n` by squaring both sides of the equation and avoid floating point.  Reworking your code for the above and simplifying a bit we get:

```
n = int(input("Start finding primes at: "))
k = 2

while True:

    if n % k == 0:
        print("Okay, look man, I totally found a non-prime number. It's", n)
        n += 1
        k = 2
        continue
    elif k * k > n:
        print("Oh yeah man, I found a prime!", n)
        n += 1
        k = 2
        continue

    k += 1
```

See if the above works any better for you.  You still need to fine tune your code to properly handle starting numbers of 2 or less.